# Parse HTTP request MATLAB TCPSERVER

Tags: matlab, tcpserver

Hi Is it possible to parse HTTP get/post requests using tcpserver in MATLAB? I followed [this](https://nl.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/799337-how-can-i-best-receive-data-from-a-web-hook-into-matlab) link but it seems it's not possible. Does anyone know what can be done in this case? When I send a Http request, I see the string data being recieved by the server but it seems to me that I might have to write my own parser. Has anybody encountered such situation?

Answer (score 1):

The Matlab `tcpserver` function just does TCP/IP. That's a lower-level network protocol; it doesn't support the higher-level HTML protocol/data format.

There's an `htmlTree` function in the Matlab [Text Analytics Toolbox](https://www.mathworks.com/products/text-analytics.html) if you want to pay $1,000 for that. There's no HTML parser in core Matlab.

But Matlab has an embedded Java JVM, so you can [use Java libraries in Matlab code](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/using-java-libraries-in-matlab.html), and there's free and open-source Java HTML parsing libraries, like [Jsoup](https://jsoup.org/). You can pull one of those in by sticking its JARs on your Matlab's Java classpath (using `javaaddpath(...)`) and script it with M-code.

Or do the same with a Python HTML parsing library using Matlab's [Python External Interface API](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/call-python-libraries.html).

If you decide to write your own HTML parser in Matlab, you are going to be sad. :(

Comment: “you are going to be sad” — I have never attempted to write an HTML parser, but I can certainly imagine this to be true.